# How can I save my miniature roses?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, roses, outdoor

I bought these miniature roses about 3 months ago from the supermarket, so I was aware they might not live long. However, they seemed to do well. After I removed the dead flowers and moved them near the window, they started growing new leaves, they almost doubled their size. I was very surprised that they also bloomed again.

[image]

In the last days I started to notice that their leaves are slowly turning yellow, starting from the bottom. Here are some pictures of them where you can see the leaves:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Are they dying?  Should I plant them outside? The temperature outside is about 20C during day and around 10C during night, not very sunny unfortunately.

Comment: Related: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20013/how-to-save-roses-commercially-potted-gift-ones-with-few-roots/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plant them outside if you have a space for them, but you need to harden them off first, by placing outside during the day for 2 or 3 hours the first day, increasing the time you leave them out over a week or so, until they're out all night (preferably a milder night). After that, they can be planted in the ground.

If you want to keep them in pots (indoors or out) the one in the image needs a larger pot, probably two sizes bigger than the pot it's currently in - use fresh potting soil to pack round the rootball in the new pot, which should have drainage holes. Keep the soil level at the same height it is now round the stems, but ensure the soil is about half an inch down from the edge of the pot, not near the top of the pot because it makes it easier to water. Water in well once potted up or planted out and keep watered ongoing, even in the ground during dry spells.